# delphi : Access violation calling stdcall external C DLL?

Tags: c, delphi

I've a Delphi project and I'm having a problem when calling a specific function from a external C DLL.

dll.h:

```c
#ifndef _DLL_H_
#define _DLL_H_

#if BUILDING_DLL
#define DLLIMPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLIMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
DLLIMPORT unsigned char *decrypted(char *datain,int len);
#endif
```

dllmain.c:

```c
#include "dll.h"
#include <windows.h>
DLLIMPORT unsigned char * decrypted(char *textin ,int len)
{
    MessageBox(0,textin,"Hi",MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL,DWORD fdwReason,LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch(fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {
            break;
        }
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        {
            break;
        }
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        {
            break;
        }
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Delphi project:

```pascal
...
const
  NomDLL = 'crpt.dll';
  function decrypted(datain : PAnsiChar ;len : integer) : PAnsiChar;   stdcall; external NomDLL;

text := 'xxxx';
decrypted(PAnsiChar(text),length(text));

end.
```

The decrypted function works perfectly without parameters?

Comment: The function `decrypted` doesn't look like stdcall.

Comment: not working without stdcall.  The textin is not clear

Comment: its work with  cdecl , I do not know why

Comment: As MikeCAT already said, the DLL function is not exported with ``stdcall``! When no calling convention is set, then C uses ``cdecl``.

Comment: @DelphiCoder That is not guaranteed, though. The default calling convention used when no calling convention is specified in code is compiler-defined.  The *default* is usually `cdecl`, but most compilers allow that default to be specified in their configuration.